# BufferedReader not reading whole online XML file

Tags: java, xml, bufferedreader

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException 
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    URL link1 = new URL("xmlFileHere");
    InputStream xml = link1.openStream();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(xml);
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(reader);
    while(reader1.readLine()!= null)
    {
        System.out.println(reader1.readLine());
    }

}
```

Hello. As you can see my `BufferedReader` is not reading the whole online XML file, I don't know why. Any idea why this happens?
Thank you.

Comment: BTW .. Make sure you use trim() to remove leading and trailing unwanted characters after you read from a file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
while(reader1.readLine()!= null)   // reading here
{
System.out.println(reader1.readLine());  // and here
}
```

You are skipping a line each time you loop...

Do,

```
String line=null;
while((line=reader1.readLine())!= null)   // reading here
{
System.out.println(line);  // and displaying here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `Scanner` which thanks to `hasNextLine()` method makes iterating more intuitive.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader1);
while (scanner.hasNextLine() ) {//check if next line exists
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());//use this next line
}
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this idiom

```
for (String curLine; (curLine=reader1.readLine()) != null;) {
    System.out.println(curLine);
}
```

it's good because `curLine` var is needed only inside loop

Answer (score 1):

Change this in your code.

```
String curLine = "";
while((curLine=reader1.readLine())!= null)
{
    System.out.println(curLine);
}
```

`reader1.readLine()` will read your line in while loop and again inside while loop which create problem in not displaying whole XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the while loop.

```
    String line;
    while( (line=reader1.readLine() ) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```